# targetting an update panels post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if there was a way to determine when a post-back occured in an update panel. Looking for something similar to (IsPostBack).

I'm using ASP.NET, with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback.aspx):

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
{
    // In a request from an update panel
}
else {
    // Not in a request from an update panel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try IsCallBack - should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to determine this on the server side or client side?  There is a server-side UpdatePanel load event that you can override I think.  Client side can be done by following these instructions - http://forums.asp.net/t/1254188.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If any update occured in a page , you can find which updatepanel(s) is caused postback.
It is possible by javascript

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoadedHandler);

function PageLoadedHandler(sender, args)
{
    //this event is raised after all content on the page is refreshed.
    //Whether it was refreshed bacause of a synchronous or asynchronous
    if (TargetPanelWasUpdated(args.get_panelsUpdated(), "UpdatePanel1") )
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

function TargetPanelWasUpdated(panelsUpdated, targetPanelID) 
{
     // NOTE: Multiple UpdatePanels will be included in the list unless  
     // you set each panel's UpdateMode property to Conditional.
     var matched = false; 
     for (i = 0 ; i < panelsUpdated.length; i++) {   
         if (panelsUpdated[i].id == targetPanelID) {
             matched = true;
             break;
     }                       
 }    
 return matched;    
}
```